# I'm not getting proper output for checking a string to be palindrome or not

Tags: python

I am not getting expected output while running the program

```
print('----------palindrome or not---------')
line=input('enter a line:-')
length=len(line)
a=0
if(length%2==0):
    length1=length/2
else:
    length1=(length+1)/2
for i in range (0,length-1):
    if(line[i]==line[length-2]):
        a+=1
if(a==length1):
    print("entered line is palindrome")
else:
    print("entered line is not palindrome")
```

**OUTPUT**:
[image]

Comment: try changing `if(line[i]==line[length-2]):` --> `if(line[i]==line[length-1-i]):`. Also change `range (0, length-1)` --> `range (0, length1)`

Comment: Actually the output is correct. What is wrong is your algorithm.

Comment: `if(line[i]==line[length-2])` You're comparing the `i`th character to the second-to-last character.  Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 2):

What about this simple function?

```
def is_palindrome(text):
    return text == text[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.8/bin/python3

print('----------palindrome or not---------')

line = input('enter a line:-')
length = len(line)
half_length = length // 2

for i in range(0, half_length):
    if line[i] != line[length - i - 1]:
        print("entered line is not palindrome")
        break
else:
    print("entered line is palindrome")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply use the reversed() function on the input and check if both are same.

```
def palindrome(userinput):
    # reverse the text
    reversed_text = ''.join(reversed(userinput))

    # if user inputs blank
    if len(userinput) < 1:
        return False

    # check if reversed_text == userinput
    if (reversed_text == userinput):
        return True
    else:
        False

userinput = input()
text = palindrome(userinput)

if text:
    print('Entered line is palindrome')
else:
    print('Entered line is not palindrome')
```

This works fine.